# XPath selecting element and following element

Tags: xpath

I have a large table of data roughly laid out as follows. As requested below is a full sample rather than a simplification.

```
<table class="grid resultRaceGrid" id="mainGrid">
<tr>
    <th width="10">&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>HORSE/SP</th>
    <th>AGE</th>
    <th>WGT</th>
    <th>TRAINER/JOCKEY</th>
    <th>OR</th>
    <th>TS</th>
    <th>RPR</th>
    <th width="10">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="11" class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="last"><a href="/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=443557&amp;r_date=2007-11-21&amp;popup=yes" class="bull"><b>&laquo;</b></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="nowrap noPad"><h3>1 </h3></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="dstDesc"></td>
    <td class="nowrap"><span class="black"><a href="#" id="noteIcon_673823" class="pencil" onclick="return false;"><!-- --></a><b><a href="/horses/horse_home.sd?horse_id=673823" onclick="return popup(this, {width:695, height:800})" title="Full details about this HORSE">Andytown</a></b> (IRE) 6/4F <img src="http://ui.racingpost.com/ico/tipping-success.gif" class="shilda" title="Tipped by Topspeed" alt="" /></span></td>
    <td class="black">5</td>
    <td class="nowrap black"><span>11-1&nbsp;<span class="lightGray"></span></span></td>
    <td class="nowrap black"><a href="/horses/trainer_home.sd?trainer_id=13176" onclick="return popup(this, {width:695, height:800})" title="Full details about this TRAINER">N G Richards</a></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="lightGray">&mdash;</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="lightGray"><span class="red bold">*</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="last"><span class="red bold">*</span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="last"><a href="/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=450083&amp;r_date=2008-03-08&amp;popup=yes" class="bull"><b>&raquo;</b></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><span class="pedigrees">ch g <a href="/bloodstock/stallionbook/stallion_home.sd?horse_id=42337&amp;popup=1" onclick="return popup(this, {width:734, height:800})" title="Full details about this STALLION">Old Vic</a> - <a href="/bloodstock/dam_home.sd?horse_id=519458" onclick="return popup(this, {width:695, height:800})" title="Full details about this DAM ">Pitfire (IRE)</a> (<a href="/bloodstock/stallionbook/stallion_home.sd?horse_id=303796&amp;popup=1" onclick="return popup(this, {width:734, height:800})" title="Full details about this STALLION">Parliament</a>)</span></td>
    <td class="lightGray"><a href="/horses/jockey_home.sd?jockey_id=82320" onclick="return popup(this, {width:695, height:800})" title="Full details about this JOCKEY">Fearghal Davis</a><sup>5</sup></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowComment hideComment">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="7"><div class="commentText">   Went prominent 6th, challenged 2 out, soon ridden, narrow advantage last, forged clear towards finish (tchd 7-4)</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="11" class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I have the following XPath which allows me to correctly match an entire row of interest.

**My question is**: how can I select this `tr` together with the following two `tr` elements (following it).

```
$xpath->query("//table[@id='mainGrid']//tr[descendant::a[contains(@href,'horse_home')]]"
```

Comment: There is no `<a>` elements in your example. Please provide a sample that the XPath can be applied on.

Comment: @gordon. code sample updated.

Comment: There is *no question* at all! Also, the sentence "I also want to match the following two rows." doesn't make any sense. What two rows? Which two rows? What is the problem you have encountered? Please, clarify.

Comment: @dimitre the following two rows in the table. tr.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only correct solution so far -- the currently accepted one isn't selecting the nodes you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//table[@id='mainGrid']
      //tr[descendant::a
              [contains(@href,'horse_home')]
          ]
 |
    //table[@id='mainGrid']
          //tr[descendant::a
                  [contains(@href,'horse_home')]
              ]
               /following-sibling::tr[not(position() > 2)]
```

This XPath expression refines your previous selection, specifying that the union of it with at-most two `tr` following siblings (of your previous selected `tr` element) should be selected.

Comment: excellent. i thought i could get away without specifying the original tr match. this is absolutely perfect, and much appreciated.

Comment: @esryl: It could be just one compact expression without the need of union, but unfortunately XPath doesn't have a `following-sibling-or-self::` axis.

Comment: +1 Good answer. About following-sibling-or-self: check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, without the union of two absolute expressions:

```
//table[@id='mainGrid'] 
   //tr[(self::tr|preceding-sibling::tr[not(position() > 2)])
              [descendant::a 
                  [contains(@href,'horse_home')] 
              ]
       ]
```

As proof, suppose this reduce input sample:

```
<table id="mainGrid">
    <tr>1</tr>
    <tr>2</tr>
    <tr>3</tr>
    <tr>
        <a href="/horses/horse_home.sd"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>5</tr>
    <tr>6</tr>
    <tr>7</tr>
    <tr>
        <a href="/horses/horse_home.sd"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>8</tr>
    <tr>9</tr>
    <tr>10</tr>
</table>
```

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="
//table[@id='mainGrid']
   //tr[(self::tr|preceding-sibling::tr[not(position() > 2)])
              [descendant::a
                  [contains(@href,'horse_home')]
              ]
       ]
"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<tr>
    <a href="/horses/horse_home.sd" />
</tr>
<tr>5</tr>
<tr>6</tr>
<tr>
    <a href="/horses/horse_home.sd" />
</tr>
<tr>8</tr>
<tr>9</tr>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: Good answer, +1. However do note that you still have a union. Also, it must be `following-sibling::tr`, not `preceding-sibling::tr`.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right. That's why I've say "the union of two **absolute expressions** ". In this case is `preceding-sibling` the needed axis, because the meaning is: *a descendant `tr` for wich itself or a not more than second preceding has a descendant `a` containg 'horse_home' in `href` attribute*

Comment: @Alejandro: This expression is selecting up to three `tr` siblings from which at least one satisfies the predicate. This is not what the OP wants. He wants that exactly the first `tr` satisfies the predicate and he doesn't care whether or not the next two siblings satisfy the predicate.

Comment: @Dimitre: This selects exactly what the OP wants: me or one of my two predeceding sibling satisties the condition.

Comment: @Alejandro: Please, read the question well, He says: "My question is: how can I select this tr together with the following two tr elements (following it)." he wants the node selected initially with his XPath expression and its following two `tr` siblings.

Comment: @Alejandro: Your XPath expression may select three `tr` elements, of which only the last satisfies the condition. But the OP wants that the first satisfies the condition.

Comment: @Dimitre: Ok, I'm not saying this expression follows exactly the... "grammatic" (?) meaning of the question, but it's semanticly equivalent. You are missing the meaning of the second step `//tr`

Comment: @Alejandro: Do you agree that the expression you are proposing will select three sibling `tr` elements of which only the last satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 0):

`$xpath->query("//table[@id='mainGrid']//tr[descendant::a[contains(@href,'horse_home')] | //table[@id='mainGrid']//tr[descendant::a[contains(@href,'horse_home')]/following-sibling::tr[position() < 3]"` is one way (which is not efficient I think).

With XPath 2.0 (probably not supported by your PHP API) you could use `$xpath->query("//table[@id='mainGrid']//tr[descendant::a[contains(@href,'horse_home')]/(., following-sibling::tr[position() < 3])`.

Comment: honnen, i have updated the code sample. your code works well for matching the following rows but does not return the matched row as well.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should definitely consider using Xpath axes.
`following-sibling` and `previous-sibling`

Your expression then, should look something like this:

```
$xpath->query("//table[@id='mainGrid']/tr[descendant::a[contains(@href,'horse_home')]/following-sibling::tr[2]")
```

Comment: i have been playing with XPath axes, but cannot get it to return self and sibilings.

Comment: @esryl: I see in ur example code you 've used //table//tr..  A note: avoid de //tr  .what your basically saying is "tr occuring anywhere int the table". Not a good idea.

Comment: right, nice use of axis. when i loop through my matched row, i now do another query tied to the original node using following-sibling. doing the trick. the method you have led me to actually gives me much more control. plus thanks for the tip on //